# Colorscheme (jellybeans) doesn't work properly on startup in vim

Tags: vim

Recently I've installed jellybeans color scheme under `~/.vim/colors`. Everything was ok when I use it in current session. After placing simple line `colorscheme jellybeans` in `.vimrc` and restarting vim I got the following:

[image]

`echo g:colors_name` gives `jellybeans` value. As you can see the color scheme isn't properly displayed and look different. So when I switch color scheme again using `colorscheme monokai`, `colorscheme jellybeans` the appearance become correct:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps `:set background=light` (or `dark`) is needed too?

Comment: `set t_Co=256` option solve the problem) Post it with mine addition and I just accept it.

Comment: Since you found the answer on your own you should probably just post an answer yourself and mark it accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved when I explicitly set to use 256 colors. To enable 256 colors in vim, put this into your `.vimrc` before setting the colorscheme:

```
set t_Co=256
colorscheme jellybeans
set background=dark
```

Also setting background to dark is useful for some themes like gruvbox to get appropriate kind of theme (light or dark). So I force vim to use "dark variant" of theme if it is possible.